# Appending successive rows to Python dataframe

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create a bidimensional numpy array.

I tried this:

```
import numpy as np

result = np.empty
np.append(result, [1, 2, 3])
np.append(result, [4, 5, 9])
```

1.The dimensions of the array are: `(2, 3)`. How can I get them?

I tried:

```
print(np.shape(result))
print(np.size(result))
```

But this prints:

```
()
1
```

2.How can I access a specific element in the array?

I tried this:

```
print(result.item((1, 2)))
```

But this returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 10, in <module>
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'item'
```

Answer (score 3):

Ideally you should be testing this sort of code in an interactive session, where you can easily get more information on the steps.  I'll illustrate in `ipython`.

```
In [1]: result = np.empty
In [2]: result
Out[2]: <function numpy.core.multiarray.empty>
```

This is a function, not an array.  The correct use is `result = np.empty((3,))`.  That is you have to call the function with a desired size parameter.

```
In [3]: np.append(result, [1,2,3])
Out[3]: array([<built-in function empty>, 1, 2, 3], dtype=object)
```

`append` has created an array, but look at the contents - the function and 3 numbers.  And the `dtype`.  Also `np.append` returns a result.  It does not work in-place.

```
In [4]: result.item((1,2))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-51f2b4be4f43> in <module>()
----> 1 result.item((1,2))

AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'item'
```

Your error tells us that `result` is a function, not an array.  The same thing you set at the start.

```
In [5]: np.shape(result)
Out[5]: ()
In [6]: np.array(result)
Out[6]: array(<built-in function empty>, dtype=object)
```

In this case the function versions of `np.shape` and `np.size` aren't diagnostic, because they first convert `result` into an array.  `result.shape` would have given an error.

The underlying problem is that you are using a list model

```
result = []
result.append([1,2,3])
result.append([4,5,6])
```

But the array `append` is misnamed, and misused.  It is just a front end to `np.concatenate`.  If you don't understand `concatenate`, you probably won't use `np.append` right.  In fact, I would argue that you shouldn't use `np.append` at all.

---

The correct way to use append is to start with an array that has size 0 dimension, and reuse the result:

```
In [7]: result = np.empty((0,3),int)
In [8]: result
Out[8]: array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=int32)
In [9]: result = np.append(result,[1,2,3])
In [10]: result
Out[10]: array([1, 2, 3])
In [11]: result = np.append(result,[4,5,6])
In [12]: result
Out[12]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

But maybe that isn't what you want?  Even I'm misusing `append`.

Back to the drawing board:

```
In [15]: result = []
In [16]: result.append([1,2,3])
In [17]: result.append([4,5,6])
In [18]: result
Out[18]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
In [19]: result = np.array(result)
In [20]: result
Out[20]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

With a real array, your `item` expression works, though usually we use `[]` indexing:

```
In [21]: result[1,2]
Out[21]: 6
In [22]: result.item((1,2))
Out[22]: 6
```

---

Source code for `np.append` (note the use of `np.concatenate`):

```
In [23]: np.source(np.append)
In file: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py

def append(arr, values, axis=None):
    """
    ...
    """
    arr = asanyarray(arr)
    if axis is None:
        if arr.ndim != 1:
            arr = arr.ravel()
        values = ravel(values)
        axis = arr.ndim-1
    return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not quite the way to use `numpy` arrays. [`empty`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html) is a function. [`append`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html), for example, returns new arrays, but you're ignoring the return value.

To create the 2-d array, use this:

```
In [3]: result = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 9]])
```

To find its shape:

```
In [4]: result.shape
Out[4]: (2, 3)
```

To access a specific element:

```
In [5]: result[1][2]
Out[5]: 9
```