# nil values appended to beginnning of array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a file foo.txt with the followling lines:

```
A 10 20 30
B 40 50 60
C 70 80 90
```

I am converting these values into radians and converting them into a rotation matrix and then multiplying the rotation matrix with another rotation matrix and storing the output in a new variable before saving to a new text file.

```
import transforms3d.euler as t3d
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


# Suppress scientific notation
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

file="foo.txt"

r1=np.array([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]])
r2=np.array([[0.5,-0.30902,-0.80902],[0.30902,-0.80902,0.5],[-0.80902,-0.5,-0.30902]])
r3=np.array([[0.5,0.30902,-0.80902],[-0.30902,-0.80902,-0.5],[-0.80902,0.5,-0.30902]])
R=np.array([r1,r2,r3])

source_array=pd.read_csv(file, sep=" ", header=None)

name_array=source_array.iloc[:,0].to_numpy()
number_array=source_array.iloc[:,1:4].to_numpy()


fullstack=np.empty((1,4))
for i in range(number_array.shape[0]):
    inMat=t3d.euler2mat(np.radians(number_array[i][0]),\
                         np.radians(number_array[i][1]),\
                         np.radians(number_array[i][2]),'rzyz')
    for j in range(R.shape[0]):
        expMat=np.dot(inMat,R[j])
        expDeg=np.degrees(t3d.mat2euler(expMat))
        name=np.repeat(name_array[i],1)
        nameandDeg=np.hstack((name,expDeg)).reshape(1,4)
        fullstack=np.append(fullstack,nameandDeg,axis=0)
        np.savetxt('foo3.txt',fullstack,fmt='%s')
```

The expected output is

```
A 10.314104815618196 17.229396562958897 41.56670396614096
A -86.15202640927517 58.81289030540899 101.65925914885956
A 119.58912709295329 73.9812604867084 6.339258927995449
B 45.90468727333836 22.521012118111006 109.63942512488691
B -59.08770198050942 30.43292092265276 177.0466653835958
B -123.45325226252277 66.42599043668275 175.86346970407573
C 80.0 3.455054858914999e-15 160.0
C -63.59253616776351 -9.42984810562947 -140.45406233407002
C -127.56777089055139 26.411096630846163 -143.9360404337779
```

But after running the code in its present form an additional line appears at the beginning of the array

```
**0.0** **5e-324** **1e-323** **1.5e-323**
A 10.314104815618196 17.229396562958897 41.56670396614096
A -86.15202640927517 58.81289030540899 101.65925914885956
A 119.58912709295329 73.9812604867084 6.339258927995449
B 45.90468727333836 22.521012118111006 109.63942512488691
B -59.08770198050942 30.43292092265276 177.0466653835958
B -123.45325226252277 66.42599043668275 175.86346970407573
C 80.0 3.455054858914999e-15 160.0
C -63.59253616776351 -9.42984810562947 -140.45406233407002
C -127.56777089055139 26.411096630846163 -143.9360404337779
```

Why is this line appearing and how can i get rid of it?

Bonus question, is there a way to format the output so that all columns containing floats are represented as %0.3f?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at `fullstack` before giving it to `savetxt`.  Pay attention to `shape` and `dtype`.  If you didn't try to display the letter column, you could use the float `fmt` instead of the generic `%s`.  You could also try a `fmt='%10s %0.3f %0.3f %0.3f'` - though that will only work if the `dtype` is object, not if a string dtype.

Comment: Hi, Setting `fmt='%10s %0.3f %0.3f %0.3f` results in the following error
`ValueError: fmt has wrong number of % formats:  %10s%0.3f%0.3f%0.3f`

Comment: The number of % formats in `fmt` should match the number of columns in your array.  `np.savetxt` docs tries to explain all that you can do with the `fmt` parameter.  Ultimately it constructs (or uses) a format string just like Python printing,.e.g  `'%s %s ....' % tuple(a_row)`.

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me, I was trying your suggestion on a different version of the file. Tried running it on the correct instance, but I get the following error `TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('<U20') and format specifier ('%10s %0.3f %0.3f %0.3f )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting the line `0.0 5e-324 1e-323 1.5e-323` is because of the line `fullstack=np.empty((1,4))`. While in numerical computation `np.empty(someshape)` results in entries that amount to effectively 0, saving them to a file [still writes the in memory numerical value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44875242/numpy-empty-giving-nonempty-array), or: `0.0 5e-324 1e-323 1.5e-323`. You can prevent this line by simply changing your `np.savetxt()` line to

`np.savetxt('foo3.txt',fullstack[1:],fmt='%s')`

Or by re-thinking why it is you need to create an empty array in the first place.

Notice also if you are appending to fullstack on each iteration of the j loop. You don't need to save full stack on each iteration of the j loop, just once after the j loop has finished.

Answer (score 1):

`np.empty((1,4))` creates a new array of given shape [without initializing entries](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html). This means that the fullstack array is not empty and contains values even before you start appending `nameandDeg` to it in your loop. When you write `fullstack` to the `foo3.txt` file, the first line you see are those values.

Comment: Hi Rohan, Thanks for the insight. I have used this method before and never observed this phenomenon. In order to make the program bulletproof, could you recommend an alternative way?

Comment: Appending using np.arrays is quite inefficient -- rather, change fullstack to a regular list -- `fullstack = []` and append using a list append operation. Then to get your final result, do `np.vstack(fullstack)`.

Comment: You could initial `fullstack=np.empty((0,4))`,but the list append approach is better